# Show buttons on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Context

I have a tree view with folders (*`.directory`*):

[image]

When I mouseover on a folder, I show / hide buttons (*`.delete`* and *`.add`*).

I need to can click on this buttons.

## Question

How to let the buttons displayed when I mouseleave *`.directory`*?

## Code

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<li>
    <a class="directory">TEST</a>
    <a class="delete" style="display: none;"></a>
    <a class="add" style="display: none";></a>
</li>
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$('a.directory').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).parent().find('a.delete, a.add').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).parent().find('a.delete, a.add').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe hoverIntent() might be good has well :http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: can you post the javascript code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to wrap it

```
<div class="directory">
  <a class="value">TEST</a>
  <a class="delete" style="display: none;"></a>
  <a class="add" style="display: none";></a>
</div>
```

Then when hovering directory, it will still be hovered when you hover `.delete` or `.add`

```
$('div.directory').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).children('a.delete, a.add').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).children('a.delete, a.add').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should wrap the three elements in a block element, like a div, and do the mouseenter on the div